# Free jqGrid - Sorting order issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I was using 4.10 up till today.  I'm now upgrading to 4.13 (latest) so doing some regressions.

The first thing I've noticed is the multi sorting order.

In 4.10, the multi sorting order was by the order of the column (from left to right).

In 4.13.5 (latest), the sorting order is by what column was chosen first.

The right behavior (IMO) should be by the order of the column, so if one reorder the column, the most left column takes over and become the first element by which the sorting is applied.

the current new behavior were the sorting is based on "first selected, always first" is confusing, as the user can't tell by which order the multi sorting is applied.

Explanation:

Looking at the below 2 tables, you can see they are sorted by two columns, 'Total Runs' & 'Start Time':

[image]

[image]

Both tables holds the exact same data, sorted the exact same way, and still, they are showing different results for the sorting.

The reason for the different result, is that the index of the sorting is being built by the order of which the user clicked on the sorting, and not by the order of the columns (were the most left takes over in the index).  This is not by the standard, as users don't have any way to figure out by which column is the master out of two column in such a multi column search. In 4.10, the order was fixed, so if user wanted to change the order he had to move the columns to the right (or left).  At least this gives some indication which column takes first.

I don't say that using columns for ordering a multi search is best practice, but at least it gave some indication. In the current implementation there is no indication what so ever.  This is especially confusing when loading pre-define filtering.

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the latest version of free jqGrid is 4.13.6. It's published 10 days ago (2016-12-24). The version 4.13.5 was published at 3 Nov 2016.

The order of sorting in case of multi sorting (`multiSort: true`) is important for the final results. **The user** should be able to specify the order to have the result, which he/she want to have. The old behavior allowed no freedom for the user. Because of that the behavior was fixed. If you specify the order in `sortname` then one should just be careful in order of columns. The string

```
p.sortname + " " + p.sortorder
```

defines the order, which will be used for sorting. If you really need to have some fixed oder of sorting then you can try to "normilize" `p.sortname` inside of  `onSortCol` callback.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this is not what I was writing:  Suppose the column X is on the left of Column Y, and both are sorted.  In the old implementation the "onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder)" would have index="X, Y ", while in the new implementation X and Y are being listed as "Y, X" if user choose to click on Y first, and "X, Y" if user choose to click on X first.  suppose user don't know on which column did he click first, he have no way to know based on what the sorting is, unless starting from scratch.

Comment: In the old implementation, the order of the column was used not just as a way to re-order the column per-se, but also for applying the order of the multi-sorting.

Comment: @Tal: I don't understand what you mean under "suppose user don't know on which column did he click first". The user sees the information. For example the grid has `city` and `country` and the `continent` columns. The user can click on the `country` column first and then the `city` column to see the cities ordered by name inside of every `country`. The user can click on `continent` and then the `city` to have another results. The results will be different, but the user can easy imagine what he/she need to do. The order of columns (`country` and `city`) has no relation with content.

Comment: @Tal: The `index` parameter of `onSortCol` is just the copy of `sortname` parameter of jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/grid.base.js#L4843)). Inside of `onSortCol` you can use `var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");` to get the reference to object with all parameters. You can use `(p.sortname + " " + p.sortorder).split(",")`, reoder the elements based of any your custom criteria and set assign `p.sortname` and `p.sortorder` to new value. It allows you to change the oder of sorting columns.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I added example, in the original question.

Comment: @Tal: I can repeat, that you could have *very specific dependency* between 'Total Runs' and 'Start Time' columns. Reordering or columns by drag&drop is not an option, because 1) it's optional feature, which could be not enabled (no jQuery UI js is started or no `sortable: true` option are used) 2) one could need *specific* order of columns and still *specific* column order. I described you an above comments how you can change the behavior of sorting like you want. You need just implement "normalization" in `onSortCol`. The old ordering is just bad for more common case and thus it's fixed.

Comment: @Tal: I personally still don't understand from your example why the columns 'Total Runs' should be sorted before 'Start Time'. I could have interest for *latest tests*. Then I would click first on 'Start Time' twice and then on 'Total Runs' column. One can add `firstsortorder: "desc"` property in 'Start Time' column to order first in desc order. In any way you can use `onSortCol` to change the order if you think that the order 'Total Runs', 'Start Time' as *always* better as 'Start Time', 'Total Runs'.

Comment: Thanks, That make sense as well.  So in order to achieve the previous UX, I need to loop over the column order and fix the order within onSortCol?

Comment: @Tal: Yes. I suggest you to start with `var order = (p.sortname + " " + p.sortorder).split(",")`, where `p` is `var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");`. Every item `order` array can by splited by space (by `.split(" ")`) in the column name and the column order. You will need just reorder the columns holding the sort order and concatinate all together in one string. Finally you should cut the latest sort order and to move it to `p.sortorder`. I think that everything will be clear if you look at some examples of `p.sortname` and `p.sortorder`.